# Insert Phone number into Model Django

Tags: python, django

I am new to Python/Django I am trying to insert a Telephone number into a Field in my model.

I code I have in my models.py is

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import * 

telephone = RegexValidator(r'^\d+$', 'Only numeric characters are allowed.')

class Registration(models.Model):
      mobile_telephone = models.PositiveIntegerField(max_length=18, validators=[telephone, MaxLengthValidator])
```

the code for forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms
from registration.models import Registration

class RegistrationForm(ModelForm):
    mobile_telephone = forms.CharField(max_length=18,
                      error_messages={'invalid':'Enter a valid mobile number',
                                      'required':'Enter a valid mobile number'}
                  )
```

I have tried the models.py with IntegerField, CharField and PositiveIntegerField but none of them allow 0 at the beginning of the field.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: McAbra - The error is it wont accept numbers that start with 0. i.e - I enter 0123456789 in the form field it gets saved to the database as 123456789 missing off the 0. As its a Phone number the 0 is important.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CharField` in your model. Your regex will ensure that only numeric characters are allowed.

Comment: I have set it to a CharField but it still doesn't allow 0 and the beginning of the field once stored in the model. Is my RegEx wrong?

Comment: You need to alter the column in your database as well as updating your model. If you haven't got any important data yet, the easiest thing to do it to drop the table and re-run syncdb.

Comment: Alasdair - I've deleted my DB and re-synced it. and it now works, I didn't think about dropping it before and re-syncing it I was updating my models and running syncdb but obviously that didn't reconstruct the whole thing properly. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The syncdb command creates tables but does not modify existing ones. Django 1.7 will have schema migrations, for Django 1.6 and earlier you can use [south](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).